# Vuetify - change card loading style?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I like the option

```
<v-card :loading="loading">...
```

but I would like to change the style from linear progress bar to (for example) overlay. 
I know I can change colors by binding color instead of boolean (true).

```
<v-card :loading="'red'">...
```

But can I change the behavior in such a way? Either making the bar thicker or better, to show overlay when `loading=true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apart from hacking the CSS and change from `v-progress-linear` to `v-progress-overlay` and hoping all works as expected, you will have not many more options

the [documentation says](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#usage), for the `v-card` slots:

- *Name:* progress
- *Description:* Slot **for custom progress linear** (displayed when loading prop is not equal to Boolean False)

so you can work with a `template` but your options are limited to the "progress linear"

```js
<v-card :loading="loading">
    <template slot="progress">
        <v-progress-linear color="red" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
    </template>
    ...
</v-card>
```

as the [example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/xxwqobv?editors=1010)

Comment: How to set this in `main.css` so that this effects for all pages in my project?

Comment: @alhelal the CSS comes from Veutify, open the codePen, click Settings (top right) and see the CSS tab

Comment: There I found some external css file, I don't want this. I want something like this 

`.v-progress-linear{color: red}`

Comment: you can always override the css you want, or change the color property to whatever you need, like `<v-progress-linear color="#bada55"...`

Answer (score 6):

From the doc of vuetify, it says the loading prop can either be a string that specifies a color or a boolean.

Hence you can easily set the color loading animation by

```
<v-card :loading="loading ? 'red': null">
...
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **progress** slot on the **v-card** to show the overlay with your flavor of the loading indicator

Vuetify documentation [v-card slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-card/#slots)

```
<v-card class="ma-auto" width="300" height="300" :loading="loading">
    <template slot="progress">
        <v-overlay absolute class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
            <div>
                <v-progress-circular size="75" color="accent " :value="loadingProgress" indeterminate>
                    <span>Loading</span>
                </v-progress-circular>
            </div>
            <div>
                <v-btn text dark @click="loading = false" class="mt-3">Deactivate loading</v-btn>
            </div>
        </v-overlay>
    </template>
    <v-card-title></v-card-title>
    <v-card-text></v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
        <v-btn @click="loading = true">Activate loading</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```